# How know the url for my web api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api2, outlook-addin

I try to create an outlook add-in with a Web API.
So i have my Global class with the following code

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I have my controller with the following code

```
[HttpGet()]
        public DataResponse GetData()
        {
            return new DataResponse()
            {
                Status = "Success",
                Message = "Hello World"
            };
        }
```

So I try to send a Get request to have my DataResponse. I try to call my API in JS in my Add-in. with this code

```
$.getJSON('api/GetData')
      .done(function (data) {
      showNotification("Success", "Good job");
      }).fail(function (status) {
          showNotification('Error', "Wrong request");
});
```

My problem is I go always in my fail function. I thinks it's because my url is wrong (but I'm not totaly sure). But I don't know how find automaticly the good url to call my API.

I try to change  'api/GetData' by 'http://localhost/api/GetData' or 127.0.0.1, same error.

I try to follow this sample https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/5784 but I don't know where I missing something.

Comment: You need the controller name.

Comment: Look at your route entry you provided above: `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",` <= you are missing `controller`. What is the name of your controller? Replace "GetData" with the name of that controller. "GetData" has no business being in the URL (*according to your routing configuration*).

Comment: I see your point, but even with the controller name, I didn't reach my API. Have try : 
api/MyApiController 
https://localhost/44390/api/MyApiController 
https://localhost/api/MyApiController 
It's didn't work. Also I don't understand why in the exemple it use 
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", and call wtih  url: '../../api/SendFeedback',